# When and why would you use static with constexpr?

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

As a disclaimer, I have done my research on this before asking. I found [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865842/does-static-constexpr-variable-make-sense) but the answer there feels a bit "strawman" and didn't really answer the question for me personally. I've also referred to my handy [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) but that doesn't offer a very "dumbed down" explanation of things most times.

Basically I'm still ramping up on `constexpr`, but at the moment my understanding is that it requires expressions to be evaluated at compile time. Since they may only exist at compile time, they won't really have a memory address at runtime. So when I see people using `static constexpr` (like in a class, for example) it confuses me... `static` would be superfluous here since that is only useful for runtime contexts.

I've seen contradiction in the "`constexpr` does not allow anything but compile-time expressions" statement (particularly here at SO). However, [an article from Bjarne Stroustrup's page](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#constexpr) explains in various examples that in fact `constexpr` *does* require the evaluation of the expression at compile time. If not, a compiler error should be generated.

My previous paragraph seems a bit off-topic but it's a baseline necessary to understand why `static` can or should be used with `constexpr`. That baseline, unfortunately, has a lot of contradicting information floating around.

Can anyone help me pull all of this information together into pure facts with examples and concepts that make sense? Basically along with understanding how `constexpr` really behaves, why would you use `static` with it? And through what scopes/scenarios does `static constexpr` make sense, if they can be used together?

Comment: *"Since they may only exist at compile time, they won't really have a memory address at runtime."* They behave (can behave) just like `const` objects at runtime.

Comment: `constexpr` for variables requires the initializer to be evaluable at compile-time, such that the variable itself can be used in contexts that must be evaluable/evaluated at compile-time. The type of the variable will implicitly become `const`. That's about it, I think.

Comment: @dyp if they can behave like const at runtime, where is this documented? Can you site any sources (C++11 draft would be nice, i couldn't find relevant text in it)

Comment: The `[dcl.constexpr]` subsection mainly defines the behaviour of the `constexpr` specifier. For example, [dcl.constexpr]/9 (in N3797) says "A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`." A variable declaration which contains the `constexpr` is basically a normal declaration for an object, with some additional rules.

Comment: +1 The answer to this question is somewhat more complicated by a conflict between what experts like Bjarne and Herb say and what the standard actually guarantees. This is very finely demonstrated in the comments to my [answer here, which is also on constexpr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25891133/1708801). My feeling is this will take a little time to become clear, I have spent a lot of time attempting to gather details on C++11/14 good practices and although there are some great sources it can be difficult on some topics.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is one significant difference for function-level static variables, and that has to do with lambda-capture:

```cpp
void odr_use(int const&);

int main() {
    int non_static = 42;
    static int is_static = 42;
    []{
        odr_use(non_static); // error
        odr_use(is_static);  // OK
    }();
}
```

You are allowed to odr-use function-local static variables in lambdas without capturing them. That has nothing to do with `constexpr` - however, it usually makes little sense to enforce capture of `constexpr` variables. Therefore, `static` + `constexpr` gives a little more comfort in accessing constants from lambdas, consider:

```cpp
#include <string_view>
int main()
{
    constexpr std::string_view x = "foo";
    []{ x.data(); }; // error: odr-use of non-captured variable
}
```

In this example, the string view and its contents are constants. The use of a member function however triggers odr-use, which requires us to capture the variable. Alternatively, use `static` + `constexpr`.

Odr-use means "use according to the One-Definition Rule", and it boils down to "is the address of the object required for that operation". For member functions, the address is required to form the `this`-pointer.

---

Below you'll find the conceptual differences which also explain the effect mentioned above.

### constexpr variables are not compile-time values

A value is immutable and does not occupy storage (it has no address),
however objects declared as `constexpr` can be mutable and do occupy storage (under the as-if rule).

#### Mutability

Most objects declared as `constexpr` are immutable,
but it is possible to define a `constexpr` object that is (partially) mutable as follows:

```
struct S {
    mutable int m;
};

int main() {
    constexpr S s{42};
    int arr[s.m];       // error: s.m is not a constant expression
    s.m = 21;           // ok, assigning to a mutable member of a const object
}
```

#### Storage

The compiler can, under the as-if rule, choose to *not* allocate any storage to store the value of an object declared as `constexpr`.
Similarly, it can do such optimizations for non-constexpr variables.
However, consider the case where we need to pass the address of the object to a function that is not inlined; for example:

```
struct data {
    int i;
    double d;
    // some more members
};
int my_algorithm(data const*, int);

int main() {
    constexpr data precomputed = /*...*/;
    int const i = /*run-time value*/;
    my_algorithm(&precomputed, i);
}
```

The compiler here needs to allocate storage for `precomputed`,
in order to pass its address to some non-inlined function.
It is possible for the compiler to allocate the storage for `precomputed` and `i` contiguously;
one could imagine situations where this might affect performance (see below).

#### Standardese

Variables are either objects or references <sup>[basic]/6</sup>.
Let's focus on objects.

A declaration like `constexpr int a = 42;` is gramatically a *simple-declaration*;
it consists of *decl-specifier-seq* *init-declarator-list* `;`

From [dcl.dcl]/9, we can conclude (but not rigorously) that such a declaration declares an object.
Specifically, we can (rigorously) conclude that it is an *object declaration*,
but this includes declarations of references.
See also the discussion of [whether or not we can have variables of type `void`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25853258).

The `constexpr` in the declaration of an object implies that the object's type is `const` <sup>[dcl.constexpr]/9</sup>.
An object is a region of storage<sup>[intro.object]/1</sup>.
We can infer from [intro.object]/6 and [intro.memory]/1 that every object has an address.
Note that we might not be able to directly take this address, e.g. if the object is referred to via a prvalue.
(There are even prvalues which are not objects, such as the literal `42`.)
Two distinct complete objects must have different addresses<sup>[intro.object]/6</sup>.

From this point, we can conclude that an object declared as `constexpr` must have a unique address with respect to
any other (complete) object.

Furthermore, we can conclude that the declaration `constexpr int a = 42;` declares an object with a unique address.

### static and constexpr

The IMHO only interesting issue is the "per-function `static`", à la

```
void foo() {
    static constexpr int i = 42;
}
```

As far as I know -- but [this seems still not entirely clear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25891133) -- the compiler *may* compute the initializer of a `constexpr` variable at run-time.
But this seems pathological; let's assume it does *not* do that,
i.e. it precomputes the initializer at compile-time.

The initialization of a `static constexpr` local variable is done during *static initializtion*,
which must be performed before any *dynamic initialization*<sup>[basic.start.init]/2</sup>.
Although it is not guaranteed, we can probably assume that this does not impose a run-time/load-time cost.
Also, since there are no concurrency problems for constant initialization,
I think we can safely assume this does not require a *thread-safe* run-time check whether or not the `static` variable has already been initialized.
(Looking into the sources of clang and gcc should shed some light on these issues.)

For the initialization of non-static local variables,
there are cases where the compiler cannot initialize the variable during constant initialization:

```
void non_inlined_function(int const*);

void recurse(int const i) {
    constexpr int c = 42;
    // a different address is guaranteed for `c` for each recursion step
    non_inlined_function(&c);
    if(i > 0) recurse(i-1);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    recurse(i);
}
```

#### Conclusion

As it seems, we can benefit from static storage duration of a `static constexpr` variable in some corner cases.
However, we might lose the locality of this local variable, as shown in the section "Storage" of this answer.
Until I see a benchmark that shows that this is a real effect,
I will assume that this is not relevant.

If there are only these two effects of `static` on `constexpr` objects,
I would use `static` per default:
We typically do not need the guarantee of unique addresses for our `constexpr` objects.

For mutable `constexpr` objects (class types with `mutable` members),
there are obviously different semantics between local `static` and non-static `constexpr` objects.
Similarly, if the value of the address itself is relevant (e.g. for a hash-map lookup).

Comment: I think it is possible to pre-compute the initializer of a `constexpr` object, and then (mem)copy that value to the object e.g. in the `recurse` function. I.e., it is only a significant cost if the object is big.

Comment: Did you mean `non_inlined_function(&c);`?

Comment: @Mikhail Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 14):

Examples only. Community wiki.

### `static` == per-function (static storage duration)

Objects declared as `constexpr` have addresses just like any other object. If for some reason, the address of the object is used, the compiler might have to allocate storage for it:

```
constexpr int expensive_computation(int n); // defined elsewhere

void foo(int const p = 3) {
    constexpr static int bar = expensive_computation(42);
    std::cout << static_cast<void const*>(&bar) << "\n";
    if(p) foo(p-1);
}
```

The address of the variable will be the same for all invocations; no stack space will be required for it for every function call.
Compare to:

```
void foo(int const p = 3) {
    constexpr int bar = expensive_computation(42);
    std::cout << static_cast<void const*>(&bar) << "\n";
    if(p) foo(p-1);
}
```

Here, the addresses will be *different* for every (recursive) invocation of `foo`.

This matters for example if the object is large (e.g. an array) and we need both to use it in a context where a constant expression is required (requires a compile-time constant) and we need to take its address.

Note that since the addresses must differ, **the object might be initialized *at run-time***; for example, if the recursion depth depends on a run-time parameter. The initializer could still be pre-computed, but the result might have to be copied into the new memory region for each recursion step.
In that case, `constexpr` only guarantees that the intializer *can* be evaluated at compile-time, and the initialization *could* be performed at compile-time for a variable of that type.

### `static` == per-class

```
template<int N>
struct foo
{
    static constexpr int n = N;
};
```

Same as always: declares a variable for each template specialization (instantiation) of `foo`, e.g. `foo<1>`, `foo<42>`, `foo<1729>`. If you want to expose the non-type template parameter, you can use e.g. a static data member. It can be `constexpr` so that other can benefit from the value known at compile-time.

### `static` == internal linkage

```
// namespace-scope
static constexpr int x = 42;
```

Pretty much redundant; `constexpr` variables have internal linkage per default.
I don't see any reason currently to use `static` in this case.

Comment: I know how to use static and the different meanings. Your answer doesn't really address `constexpr` at all ::: (1) Why even use `constexpr` in this example? `static const char my_str[] ...` will do the same thing based on your explanation. (2) Why even use `static` there? (3) constexpr aside, `static` member variables **do not** declare for each instantiation. They are declared 1 time and shared for all instances *of the same type*.

Comment: Ad 1) Hmm I thought I have addressed that in the description; it seems that needs clarification. Ad 3) instantiation = template instantiation, not class -> object instantiation.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I guess I did (at least, originally) not point out what the benefits of `static` are when combined with `constexpr`. But I never intended this to be a complete answer, rather a collection of examples. I find it hard to narrow the OP's question down to something that I can answer concisely. As far as I can tell, there are some misconceptions involved.

Comment: Agreed, as I commented in the main question, I feel like the conflict between what the standard says and members of standards committee say constexpr actually does not help.

Comment: I think the part that's difficult for me is that constexpr feels like something that should be only done at compile time. It feels like the result of a constant expression should *always* be inlined, thus meaning constexpr variables or functions won't really exist at runtime, only their result. We already have const and can use it directly as needed, I see no reason why constexpr has to "behave the same", essentially IMHO this makes constexpr pointless and self defeating.

Comment: @void.pointer `constexpr` requires that the initializer *can* be computed at compile-time. Like `const` itself, it is (also) an annotation for the *programmer*, so that the compiler can check whether that promise has been broken. Similarly `constexpr` functions: The compiler could evaluate (some) non-constexpr functions at compile-time, but that is only a non-mandatory optimization. *constant expressions* (including `constexpr` functions) is the least common denominator of "compiler support" for compile-time evaluation, programmers can portably use them where a compiletime constant is required

Comment: Maybe not a very strong reason, but in C11 (not C++) implicit `static` is deprecated (§6.11.2). In general, since `static` objects do have the surprising property of a different address per TU, it's a good idea to state it explicitly.

Comment: On the second last line you say "constexpr variables have internal linkage per default". I think you mean "static variables have internal linkage per default".

Comment: @thatmarkdude `static` on namespace-scope variables is an explicit way to influence linkage. `const` or `constexpr` on namespace-scope variables *also* affects linkage (implicitly): Namespace-scope variables whose type is const-qualified by default have internal linkage (this is somewhat simplified, see http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#4 )

Answer (score 2):

***I use `static constexpr` as a replacement for unnamed enums in places where I don't know an exact type definiton, but want to query some information about the type (usually at compile time).***

There are some additional benefits to the compile time unnamed enum. Easier debugging (values show up in a debugger like a "normal" variable. Also, you get to use any type that can be constexpr constructed (not just numbers), as opposed to just numbers with an enum.

Examples:

```
template<size_t item_count, size_t item_size> struct item_information
{
    static constexpr size_t count_ = item_count;
    static constexpr size_t size_ = item_size;
};
```

Now, you can access these variables at compile time:

```
using t = item_information <5, 10>;
constexpr size_t total = t::count_ * t::size_;
```

Alternatives:

```
template<size_t item_count, size_t item_size> struct item_information
{
    enum { count_ = item_count };
    enum { size_ = item_size };
};

template<size_t item_count, size_t item_size> struct item_information
{
    static const size_t count_ = item_count;
    static const size_t size_ = item_size;
};
```

The alternatives don't have the all of the positives of static constexpr - you're guaranteed compile time processing, type safety, and (potentially) lower usage of memory (constexpr variables don't need to take up memory, they are effectively hard coded unless if possible).

Unless you start taking the address of constexpr variables (and possibly even if you still do), there is no size increase to your classes like you would see with a standard static const.

Comment: As long as you don't *define* those `static constexpr` variables (outside the class body), they do not take up space (as long as you're using a compliant compiler). Standardese: They have no definitions, hence they may not be odr-used.