# Different compilation + linking errors for static and constexpr between clang and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, static, clang, constexpr

I have the following code:

```cpp
// template_header.hpp
#ifndef TEMPLATE_HEADER_HPP
#define TEMPLATE_HEADER_HPP

namespace template_header
{
    template <int dim1>
    /*static*/ constexpr int dim2 = 0;

    template <>
    /*static*/ constexpr int dim2<2> = 3;
    template <>
    /*static*/ constexpr int dim2<3> = 5;
}

#endif
```

```cpp
// lib1.cpp
#include <array>
#include "template_header.hpp"

template <int dim1>
class lib1_class
{
public:
    std::array< double, template_header::dim2<dim1> > ar1 = {0};
};
```

```cpp
// lib2.cpp
#include <array>
#include "template_header.hpp"

template <int dim1>
class lib1_class
{
public:
    std::array< double, template_header::dim2<dim1> > ar1 = {0};
};
```

If I compile any of the `.cpp` files with `static` uncommented, GCC gives me an "explicit template specialization cannot have a a storage class" error.
If `static` is commented, I can compile both `.cpp` files and then link them together as a shared library with `g++ lib1.o lib2.o -shared -o shared_lib.so`.

However, if I compile with `static` commented out with clang, I get no problems during compilation, but I get a "multiple definition of `template_header::dim2<2>'" error during linking. If I uncomment` static`, then everything compiles and links fine.

I'm pretty confused about this, firstly given that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50489130/7736506) indicates that, since my `constexpr`'s happen in a namespace scope, they ought to automatically be `static` and therefore should pose no problem for the linker even if `static` is commented out.
Additionally, I don't understand why adding `static` beforehand would change how GCC compiles the `.cpp` files, given that it should be implicitly static.
Any explanation of the errors + possible fixes are appreciated.

Edit: I am using C++14.

Comment: The correct keyword to use in headers in `inline`, not `static`

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that I'm using C++14 -- fixed in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, without `inline` variables, I was able to get something achieving your goals working. The basic idea is to have a "backend" `struct` to hold `static` members and then [fully specialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) that `struct` to your options. This method has the added benefit of causing a compiler error if you attempt to access a member of the backend using a template parameter that has not been defined yet.

The header file would look like

```cpp
#ifndef TEMPLATED_HEADER_HPP
#define TEMPLATED_HEADER_HPP

namespace template_header {
  /**
   * the "primary" template of the backend struct
   *  notice I leave the variable we want undefined!
   *  if you prefer to have a default for all other values of dim1
   *  you would put that here
   */
  template<int dim1>
  struct backend {};

  template<>
  struct backend<2> {
    static constexpr int dim2 = 3;
  };

  template<>
  struct backend<3> {
    static constexpr int dim2 = 5;
  };

  /**
   * Helper constexpr
   *  this is optional, but makes code outside this file more readable
   *  also, I named it in a way for your source files to be unchanged.
   */
  template <int dim1>
  constexpr dim2 = backend<dim1>::dim2;
}

#endif
```

I have a working version of this idea on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwAHKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIGYapAAOqAqETgwe3r4BwemZjgLhkTEs8YnJtpj2JQxCBEzEBLk%2BfkG19dlNLQRl0XEJSSkKza3t%2BV3j/YMVVaMAlLaoXsTI7BwmGgCC5v4RyN5YANQm/m4txEwAnhfYO/tmhwzHXmcXbk7jxJisDyeByOJ0w50uBFuqUwAH0CDdCApAXsnsw2ApUkxNqc0AxZoIFOcAOxWPancmnAD0ACpqU8KeTqadYliANauU6/LwOU5EU4IQzoeic5oEU5sSoJJFkhnUyn0ikETAsVIGJXg76CU4AEWRuwZXJ5LOQ7IY6GJViJuv8pP2MvJSpVarBXz1Bvh3LFxtN6C%2BZgeFoVDPJs0cyBxAnGmFUqWIpwiYvwLEJF21p38F1tDJMVszQPtvOVqqY6td/keBcNXrZri%2BGfLgYL7pLeHDuKjMbjCdOSZT/jTAFY8wWc9bbUGqbSJ6cmQQEHhCQvTqhUg0xNOmeTtF5xszMBFgKcd5hzXyFEwAG5gjFYzCkeNUU63NanP4sVBX3nzhT3ueMJ9rGAHC%2Bk2m4Uu2zQEiAIDerWlz1tg0G9huFIAO4IAkmCYFecYQYYBAKEheDJnWAZLugAiYAAdBu8oFo6xalpc3bWhW%2BrgZGSqdvGWq9uCaawWaXysURJE2kCuYonsDHOhqLF6scTAKISigJI27GpF4sS0K2IATuM6DQdcdxfD2azaXeEZ4pBBGiUilyseC2CnC0w77Lm4lSbs3YsEwEQQEs6nuoZKBrGKZZuOcZhmKpxB%2BgGxm3JyeAAF7sFFZgaqZsXxeWAVUS0VGZGlAVZZcIoha4tBucF0FoF44WXKZ5gxUocXwQlxA3ElxXpS1ZWRTlHV5UsBXEEVqWYKVEUVdBVU1RSlKUgZdVhQNGVDW4ABsnXdclaUgBl62bTtI1jRNJWBTNK0gPNNpUpSaAqnQakJMQJASdqHArLQnADrwfgcFopCoJwbjWNYnJrBsLovDwpAEJo30rKyEgaCkv0cJIvAsCAkj%2BFR%2BOBAAnFIGhmESUjE/4ZikIDwOgxwvCESkiNA99pBwLAMCIKFz30GQFAQE9qQvYkwBcFwtM0LQSrEIRECxEjpCxBELS3Jw8NPWwggAPIMLQGvs6QWC%2BUY4jG/gfwOHgV6Ecb0aYMgDVbMDCZ1MrOmxDcxC3B4WDK/CxGaxzVAGMACgAGp4JgqG69CgPw/wggiGI7BSDIgiqWoyu6LTBhGCgEOWPoeCxIRkArCuDT2wAtLXBmpqYljWFIzN1E7DQuGaUx%2BFwIRmvMwyJP3RRZAIvd6GPDRD5KI/dJ3vQTG0ngdHodiLwIfStLPiz97Mkyr/k%2B/L7vIxcCsCjQ5sejwlhIc/X9APK4zqiBFttdbZIpzAMg4aS1RTKEBwYtxLqcXAhASBRX8P3U4Hh%2BZqQOGYJYvA2ZaCWCjAIBN/A4NwXgvBW19CcGxqQXGA4Uj014IzZmIBWZIxWFzKAPMIBIDCppAg5BKAizFkkEI%2BAiDz2TsIUQ4gM5COzuoY2d8tjw1QjcVID8iEcH%2BnTF%2BnBdYNXYcuR8b8P5fx/n/U4ACgHwNFgLaByDUH0JWBhJgWBEgBVIKjHBVF8FuNwYQzGJCyEaCokSDQ/jAkBOCZTVRxtqG2FoQjehnNmGsM0Q1ThwtUAIPnieSBgjZCp1EdIcRSgc5SL%2BDI3gcimAKO4BzTGKjKEg3UQksUqAdHv0/t/RSRgjEE18RoU4wCUlmMQXDFB0T2YYNILY%2BxlBH5YxxnjYmgDiZmAWUsxZKziZhIZpwGhdCRmYJce49xnjOD%2BGfuEzZwz0GxPgCwvm/TBZcL6TwtpEt/Doz4HQOWCslbG1VswX2IdSDa0YAQfWhtlam0MMAC2wMraLztsrR2zslTK3dpjYGXsfZ%2BwwK7VBxBg4VJWGHJgEdo6x3jowf5Qjsnp1ybICRuc9AF2MMXGwXsK6OOrtkOuDcCC%2Bn7M3Kwlg24Lxts4CArhJ79zCBEIYc8p4ZHHjkI%2Bfc0jypntKhY59hUNG3ivPIyqN4isaKfdVw917LwlbYY15RTUX1WOsG%2B/dpGKKqScjZHBdEtJxIyjpVEuk9JAQKmw4D%2BFQIOLA0xYtoEXysTspxWDXH7PwUokhNSIks3OcjJRZgZkDi2lRXNXANCBAHMTIkZhi0aC2sEVNZy0GZsxsc9ZVDa3WNIDhTIzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D) which verifies that both this works with both GCC and clang. If you were to try to call `dim2<dim1>` where `dim1` does not equal 2 or 3, then a compiler error complaining about `backend<dim1>::dims not defined` will be generated. You could add other members to the `backend` specializations, taking care to keep the names the same across the different values of `dim1`.

Total side note, why are you setting `ar1 = {0};`? From my reading of the [std array reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), this would only set the first element in the array to 0.