# How do we understand "if possible" about constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, compile-time

I've read the link about `constexpr`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

It says that the constexpr specifier declares that **it is possible** to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time.

As my understanding, it means that a variable specified by `constexpr` may or may not be evaluated at compile time.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152096/when-and-why-would-you-use-static-with-constexpr) told me the same thing: constexpr variables are not compile-time values.

However, I made a test, which confused me: https://godbolt.org/z/9ajb4xKK8

As you see, the variable `a` must be evaluated at compile time, otherwise it can't be used to declare an array. And the variable `s` can't be specified by `constexpr` because the constructor of `std::string` can't be invoked at compile time.

In a word, it seems that this testing is telling me that `constexpr` MUST evaluate the value at compile time. Otherwise, how can the variable `a` be used to declare an array?

What did I wrongly understand?

**EDIT**

I know that a `constexpr` function can be invoked at runtime or at compile time. For example, if we pass a runtime paramater to a `constexpr` function, the function would be invoked at runtime, I understand that.

But it seems that a `constexpr` variable MUST be evaluated at compile time. Can I say that any `constexpr` variable MUST be evaluated at compile time?

Comment: you found one example where `constexpr` must be at compile time. There are other examples where it can be at runtime.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I understand that a `constexpr` function can be invoked at runtime or at compile time. But I don't understand how a `constexpr` variable can be evaluated at runtime instead of at compile time. As you see, if a `constexpr` variable can't be evaluated at compile time, such as `std::string s`, an error will be generated. So why can't we say that a `constexpr` variable MUST be evaluated at compile time?

Comment: I think `constinit` is more like what you expect. As I understand it `constexpr` is rather to be more explicit and expressive. Consider you want to use `x` in a context that requires a compile time constant, you can write `const int x = foo();` which is ok in any case, but later using `x` in a context taht requires a compile time constant can fail depending on `foo`. On the other hand `constexpr int x = foo();` will fail early when `foo` is not constexpr

Comment: actually I should do some reading and rephrase that into an answer...

Comment: btw last paragraph seems to contain a typo. "But it seems that [...]. So can i say that [exactly same ...]"

Comment: cppreference is written to "simplify" the standard, See [dcl.constexpr](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr) for formal definition.

Comment: constexpr variables are compile time only, whereas constexpr functions are compile or runtime depending of context.

Comment: *"constexpr variables are not compile-time values"*. It is mostly `mutable` which introduces exception as removing constness(constexpr-ness) of subobject.

Comment: @Jarod42 Alright, I see...lol

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the compiler used in your godbolt link (gcc 11.1) allows variable-length arrays. So `a` does **not** have to be a constant expression. i.e this snippet of code below will be accepted

```
int a = 5;
int arr[a];
```

But when you do need something to be a constant expression `constexpr` will allow you to use the variable/function in it.

> **constexpr** - specifies that the value of a variable or function can appear in >constant expressions

For example, when you create an array using the `std::array` template, the size must be constant

So doing this is not OK

```
int a = 5;
std::array<int, a> arr;
```

On the other hand, `constexpr` allows `a` to be used in a constant expression, so you CAN do this

```
constexpr int a = 5;
std::array<int, a> arr;
```