Any reason to inline a constexpr variable in an source file unnamed namespace
Is there ever a reason to explicitly inline a constexpr variable that's in an unnamed namespace in a source file?
E.g. in a foo.cc:
namespace foo {
namespace {
inline constexpr uint32_t kFoo = 0;
}  // namespace

// Do something with kFoo

} // namespace foo


AFAIK it wont do anything if its defined in a source file.  That said, I would have probably written the same thing as inline constexpr is my default for all constants I define.

If something has the constexpr keyword, I thought it was implicitly given the inline keyword.  Is that not true?

@Matt That only applies to static class members.

In C++ a name of file scope that is explicitly declared const (constexpr too), and not explicitly declared extern, has internal linkage. No unnamed namespace is necessary.

duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152096/when-and-why-would-you-use-static-with-constexpr
