How to use std::array's data and other member functions in a constexpr context?
I defined the following class, expecting to be able to use std::array in a constexpr context, but calling the data function results in a compilation error.
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t N>
struct ConstexprString
{
    consteval ConstexprString(const char(&_str)[N])
        : char_array(std::to_array(_str))
    {
    }

    consteval auto Data() const -> const char*
    {
        return char_array.data();
    }

private:
    const std::array<char, N> char_array;
};

int main() 
{
    constexpr ConstexprString csexpr_str("123\\0");
    constexpr auto d = csexpr_str.Data();
}

Report compile error on MSVC
constexpr auto d = csexpr_str.Data();
// error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant


Can you show a [mre]?  I suspect that you are getting this error because of a detail you are not showing here.  (A detail that prevents csexpr_str from being constant-evaluated)

The [mre] requested above should be one block of code that we can simply copy-paste to reproduce the problem. I made it here. You can use it to update your question.

It seems like the note that goes with the error message you've quoted helps explain quite a bit: "note: failure was caused by taking the address of an object that does not have static storage duration". If you make the ConstExprString static, it works. https://godbolt.org/z/sh5zsbbWT

OT: The string "123\\0" is a string of six characters (including the actual null-terminator). The string "123\0" is a string of five characters, including two "terminators".

The Data() member isn't needed for this - just write constexpr auto a = csexpr_str.char_array;     constexpr auto d = a.data(); in your main() - that reduces the example and makes the error clearer.

@JerryCoffin constexpr on objects implies static. If compiler treats constexpr objects differently with regards to static specifier, it's a compiler bug.

@Red.Wave: I'm reasonably certain that's simply not correct. In fact, there are cases where you can show that a constexpr variable local to a recursive function must have a unique address for each of its recursive invocations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26162710/179910. The standard shows multiple examples of static constexpr variables, such as in [expr.const]/5.2 in N4950 (and in a few cases requires them, such as [numeric.limits.general]/1 static constexpr bool is_specialized = false;.)

@JerryCoffin the link doesn't contain valid answers to the question. It doesn't provide any reference or quoting to std text that justifies its differentiation between static constexpr and constexpr. It's justmeaningless to have compile-time constants with automatic duration. I don't want to require a language lawyer tag, but that's the only route to a reliable.

@Red.Wave: You're the one claiming that constexpr implies static. Can you point to any part of the standard that says so, or even hints at the idea? There are lots that specify things being static constexpr, which would clearly be redundant if your thesis was correct.

The simple fact that the object is evaluted at compile-time means it has static duration. For function local constexpr that implies static.

@Red.Wave: That doesn't contain a valid answer to the question. Where in the standard do you see a statement that constexpr forces static storage duration? [Hint: if such a thing existed, it would probably be under [expr.const]. If I had to guess, it sounds like you're treating constexpr as if it were equivalent to consteval (but of course, it's not).

@JerryCoffin I found a discussion from 2014 about the issue. It seems that there's no consensus about none-static constexpr. But proponents are not capable of giving meaningful use cases too. There has been no progress ever since. Let's just keep it there.

csexpr_str is a local variable with non-static duration.  Make it static, and GCC is happy to use it as an argument to consteval functions:
int main()
{
    static constexpr ConstexprString csexpr_str("123\\0");
    constexpr auto d = csexpr_str.Data();
}

Unless MSVC is badly broken, it should be happy too.

I know that using static or global variables can avoid this compilation error. Is there an underlying principle that can help me understand this situation? Is it because the storage for static or global variables is allocated during compile time, while local variables, even if stored on the stack, are only allocated at runtime?

That's a different question, that should be asked separately.

The size of the string passed into ConstexprString must include the null terminator if you expect the string to be a proper C-style string. Try to edit your code like the following.
#include <array>
#include <utility>  // for std::to_array

template <size_t N>
struct ConstexprString
{
    consteval ConstexprString(const char (&_str)[N])
        : char_array(std::to_array(_str))
    {
    }

    consteval auto Data() const -> const char*
    {
        return char_array.data();
    }

private:
    const std::array<char, N> char_array;
};

// Test code
constexpr ConstexprString<5> csexpr_str("123");  // Correct size: 3 characters + null terminator
constexpr auto d = csexpr_str.Data();  // This should now compile correctly


The string "123\\0" is a proper C-type null-terminated string. Its size might not be what's expected, but it's still valid.

Changing the variables to globals does fix the problem - but you sneaked that in with a totally irrelevant "explanation".  (Though your code doesn't compile, since you instantiated with N=5 instead of N=4).
