# Non-defining declarations for `void` "objects": which part of C++ standard prohibits them? Or does it?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration, void, incomplete-type

There are at least two places in C++ standard that prohibit *defining* objects with incomplete types (http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#5, http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#5). However, providing *non-defining declarations* for objects of incomplete type is generally allowed in C++. And I don't seem to be able to pinpoint the specific part that would prohibit declaring incomplete "objects" of `void` type in that fashion. (Granted, `void` is not an object type in C++, but neither are reference types, for one example.) So, is this

```
extern void a;
```

really ill-formed in C++?

In C providing non-defining declarations for `void` objects (as shown above) is allowed and both GCC and Clang accept the above in C code (definitions are not allowed, of course). But in C++ code both compilers issue errors for such declarations. Which part of the standard makes them to do so?

`[basic.fundamental]` lists possible uses of `void` type (http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.fundamental-13) but it does not appear to be intended as a complete list.

Comment: References (like pointers) form a *compound type* with the type they are applied to. So they are part of the type information of the variable being declared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't we declare a variable of type void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853258/why-cant-we-declare-a-variable-of-type-void)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the relevant passages are the following:

> **[dcl.stc]**
>
> [5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.stc#5) The `extern` specifier shall be applied only to the declaration of a variable or function.
>
> **[basic]**
>
> [6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#6) A *variable* is introduced by the declaration of a reference
>   other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable's
>   name, if any, denotes the reference or object.
>
> **[basic.types]**
>
> [8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#8) An *object type* is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a
>   function type, not a reference type, and not cv void.

`a`, being a variable declaration, must denote a reference or an object according to [basic]¶6. That covers references which are indeed not object types. However, since void is neither a reference nor an object type, the declaration is ill-formed.

Comment: And as an aside, even if that declaration was not ill-formed, you could never form the definition that it is supposed to declare. so why allow it?

Comment: Well, one can also ask "Why disallow it?" if disallowing it requires extra effort. As I stated in the question, C actually allows it, even though a matching definition is impossible to form.

Comment: @AnT - IIRC the C++ standard does try to disallow certain truly pointless or erroneous constructs whenever it can identify them.